# How do I clear this list/array? Forms

Tags: c#, arrays, list, forms

I am making a To Do program in windows forms where I want to save events, what day/hour they happen and the priority.

I am filling a listbox with information, then I want to start over and have a clean slate.  The listbox looks cleared but once another input is made all the old ones show up as well.  I think this is because I havent cleared the list/array.

I've tried using Array.Clear(), but I dont know whether to make a new method for it or put it in my InitalizeGUI().  I also don't know if I am clearing a list or an array as it is a list to start with but is converted to a string array.

```
class TaskManager
    {
        private List<Task> todo;

        public TaskManager()
        {
            todo = new List<Task>();
        }

        public Task GetItem (int index)
        {
            if (!CheckIndex(index))
                return null;

            return todo[index];
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return todo.Count; }
        }

        public bool AddItem (Task itemIn)
        {
            bool ok = false;
            if (itemIn != null)
            {
                todo.Add(itemIn);
                ok = true;
            }
            return ok;
        }

        private bool CheckIndex (int index)
        {
            return(index >= 0) && (index < todo.Count);
        }

        public string [] ListToStringArray()
        {
            string[] taskArray = new string[Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) taskArray[i] = todo[i].ToString();
            return taskArray;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Taskmanager class.  Do i make a method to clear this list/array, and should it be made in TaskManager or Mainform?

I've tried all the ways I could from googling online but I can't figure it out.

Hopefully someone knows how to help!

Best regards

Comment: I just searched on google how to clear a list and the first hit was the answer. As to other part of the question... you should properly make a public clear method which clears the private list.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. Just clear the list with `list.Clear()`, that's it?

Comment: Where do I add it and how do i call it in InitializeGui()?

Comment: @EmilJärudd Add a method `TaskManager.Clear()` which will call `todo.Clear();`, and then call `TaskManager.Clear()` from your `InitializeGui()`?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I am completely lost.  What type of a method should TaskManager.Clear() be and how would it look?  Thanks a lot for helping:)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Fixed now, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new public method in TaskManager class that clears the 'todo' private variable.:

```
public void ClearList()
{
todo.Clear();
}
```

Call it when you need your list empty. Eg.: At the InitGui() method.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Finally got it to work.  The problem was that i didn't specify the class;  
Mainform;   --> TaskManager itemManager = new TaskManager();  <--  Of course i had to write:  itemManager.ClearList(); to call the class.    Thanks for helping!